# Unix shell - file test operator without argument

Tags: bash, unix

```
prompt> if [ -f ]; then echo "true"; fi
true
```

Why does the if condition evaluate to true? Isn't -f supposed to need an argument?

```
prompt> if [ -f $1 ]; then echo "true"; fi
```

Does it mean I always need to check if the argument $1 is not empty before proceeding to the if condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `[ -f ]` results in a successful exit code is because of this bit [from the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions):

> -n string
>
> string
>
> True if the length of string is non-zero.

Which is also explained [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-test) when talking about `test`/`[`:

> The test and [ builtins evaluate conditional expressions using a set
>   of rules based on the number of arguments.
>
> 0 arguments
>
> The expression is false.
>
> 1 argument
>
> The expression is true if and only if the argument is not null.
>
> 2 arguments
>
> If the first argument is ‘!’, the expression is true if and only if the second argument is null. If the first argument is one of the unary conditional operators (see Bash Conditional Expressions), the expression is true if the unary test is true. If the first argument is not a valid unary operator, the expression is false.
>
> 3 arguments
>
> ...
>
> 4 arguments
>
> ...
>
> 5 or more arguments
>
> ...

So while you expect to be using the two argument test the shell sees the one argument version and tests the string `-f` against the null string.

That is `[ word ]` is equivalent to `[ -n word ]`.

You can avoid this problem by quoting your variable in the test:

```
if [ -f "$1" ]; then echo true; fi
```

In general you want to **always** quote variable expansions.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid that scenario using `if [[ ]]` syntax or simply by quoting the variable `$1` in your current code.

Example:

```
if [ -f "$1" ]; then echo "true"; fi
```

Or:

```
if [[ -f $1 ]]; then echo "true"; fi
```

Note: Always try to quote variables.